# Can a Kshatriya ask for alms according to Hindusim?

Tags: vedas, puranas, dharma-shastras, manu-smriti

I've read somewhere, most probably in some shastra, that in case of scarcity or lack of resource, and if it's a question of survival, a Kshatriya can ask for alms. What are your views regarding this?

Kindly adhere to shastras only with reference if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manusmriti 10.95 says

> जीवेदेतेन राजन्यः सर्वेणाप्यनयं गतः ।
>   न त्वेव ज्यायंसीं वृत्तिमभिमन्येत कर्हि चित् ॥ ९५ ॥
>
> jīvedetena rājanyaḥ sarveṇāpyanayaṃ gataḥ |
>   na tveva jyāyaṃsīṃ vṛttimabhimanyeta karhi cit || 95 ||
>
> The Kṣatriya, fallen in adverse circumstances, shall >subsist by means of all this; but he shall never think of >arrogating to himself the higher occupations.—(95)

Now begging for alms is not a prescribed activity of Brahmins. So Kshatriya seeking alms (which by default means that he is trying to survive ) is allowed

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Begging for alms is not a prescribed for Brahmins? Are you sure about it?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma - Believe so. If not mistaken , begging only comes in when you are on the path of sanyasi

Comment: Begging is prescribed for a student (brahmachari). This includes Brahmins as well. I remember there is a verse Grihastas (married) should also beg alms. Brahmacharis take cooked rice. Grihastas take uncooked rice. I don't have the verse with me right now.